# Is it good to change threads to async-await template?

Tags: multithreading, async-await

Some time ago I was faced with a task, described below, the project used .net 4.0 and now I am wonder if it would be good to use async-await in that situation if there was such possibilty(the method is run by delegate should download lots of files). I have read different articles to clear up my curiosity but not sure that I have rigt thoughts.

```
 public static void StartBackgroundThread(ParameterizedThreadStart 
        threadstart, string name = "", object parameter = null)
    {
        if (ConcQueue.Count == 0)
        {
            ConcQueue.Enqueue(threadstart);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var element in ConcQueue)
            {
                if (element.Method.Name == threadstart.Method.Name)
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!HasBackgroundThread)
        {
            HasBackgroundThread = true;
            try
            {
                ParameterizedThreadStart result;
                ConcQueue.TryDequeue(out result);
                _backgroundThread = new Thread(result) { Name = name };
               _backgroundThread.Start(parameter);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

how would you refactor this piece of code in terms of threads\async? and would you? and is it better to use async-await or threads?

Answer (score 1):

> how would you refactor this piece of code in terms of threads\async? and would you?

I would refactor the code that *uses* this code. This code is tightly tied to the `Thread` type, and it would be difficult to rewrite without rewriting the calling code anyway.

> and is it better to use async-await or threads?

`async` and threads are quite different. The `Thread` type itself is very outdated and should be replaced with more modern approaches (`Parallel`, thread pool, etc) for all use cases except COM interop. The question of whether to use `async` or parallel/thread pool depends on what you're trying to do; anything CPU-bound could use parallel/thread pool, with I/O-bound operations using `async`.